# Pyinstaller Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a screen reader in python3.6.9 as a college assignment.

The python script works fine but when I try to create an app out of it using PyInstaller 4.3, it shows error message:

> `PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import
> module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc required by hook for module
> /.../site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-pydoc.py.
>
> Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc actually
> exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of
> /.../site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-pydoc.py:`

It also shows many warnings while building the executable.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can try:

`pyinstaller your_file.py --exclude-module pydoc`